# How to split a string on occurrence of 3rd space in it?

Tags: c#

I have to split a string on every 3rd occurrence of space in it in C#. And then split the same string backward with every 3rd space encountered from the end.

I have tried using `IndexOf()` with `Substring()` like

```
string sub1 = q.Substring(q.IndexOf(q.Split(' ')[3]));
```

Eg. of string - `Where can I find medicine for headache`

Expected Output -

1. 3 substrings as - `Where can I`, `find medicine for`, `headache`
2. 3 substrings as - `Where`, `can I find`, `medicine for headache`

Comment: Hint: Split, Take, Join.

Comment: @ZoharPeled can you please show some examples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The forward case is fairly straightforward. Split by a space so you have all elements in one array and then `Skip` and `Take`as necessary:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitForward(string input, char c, int n)
{
    var items = input.Split(c);
    var x = 0;
    while(x<items.Length)
    {
        yield return String.Join(c.ToString(), items.Skip(x).Take(n));
        x += n;
    }
}
```

The backward case is a little more complex, the first time you `Take` it might not be the full 3 items:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitBackward(string input, char c, int n)
{
    var items = input.Split(c);
    var x = 0;
    var take = items.Length%n;
    while(x<items.Length)
    {
        if(take == 0) take = n;
        yield return String.Join(c.ToString(), items.Skip(x).Take(take));
        x += take;
        take = n;

    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var input = "Where can I find medicine for headache";            
var forwards = SplitForward(input, ' ',3).ToArray();
var backwards = SplitBackward(input, ' ',3).ToArray();
```

Live example:   https://rextester.com/OLUK79677

Comment: Your `SplitBackward` is over-complicated. Simply reverse the `items` array and do the same as `SplitForward`...

Comment: @ZoharPeled By doing so required output is not produced.

Comment: @ZoharPeled then the results come out backwards. It's just complicated enough (without being overly complex) to produce the desired output

Comment: @Jamiec Thank you. Your answer produces desired results but in backward case, if the modulus i.e. take = items.Length%n results in 0 (take=0) then an empty string is added to the result.

Comment: so at the start of the `while` loop just add `if(take == 0) take = n`

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there are tons of more elegant ways of doing this but the following for loop generates the output you want.

```
    string text = "Where can I find medicine for headache"; 
    var splitText = text.Split(' ');

    var fromStart = "";
    var fromEnd = "";

    for(int i = 0; i< splitText.Length;i++){

        fromStart = fromStart + splitText[i];
        fromEnd = fromEnd + splitText[i];

        if((i+1) % 3 == 0 && i != splitText.Length - 1)
            fromStart = fromStart + ", ";
        else
            fromStart = fromStart + " ";

        if(i % 3 == 0 && i != splitText.Length - 1)
            fromEnd = fromEnd + ", ";
        else
            fromEnd = fromEnd + " ";
    }

    Console.WriteLine(fromStart);
    Console.WriteLine(fromEnd);
```